# Docker Containers having issues

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Our developers handed off our project to us at a sudo-demo stage and I am trying to get the enviroment set up on my local development machine. Containerization is new to me but I'm figuring it out.

I have four docker containers:

```
CONTAINER ID - name - ports
ce05f4675d70 - laradock_nginx_1 - 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp
bd900f08e9b3 - laradock_php-fpm_1 - 9000/tcp                                  
75a7aa1698de - laradock_workspace_1 - 0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp
1d8c69a06ae4 - laradock_mongo_1 - 0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
```

I have an app located at yellowcard.app and an api at api.yellowcard.app this is setup in my hosts file.

All four containers are up and running, but all of my api calls result in a 500 response code. I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

**Mongodb Logs**

```
2017-07-28T07:13:51.034+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=1d8c69a06ae4
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-07-28T07:13:51.040+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-07-28T07:13:51.041+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-07-28T07:13:51.041+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-07-28T07:13:51.119+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-07-28T07:13:51.119+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2017-07-28T07:13:51.119+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-28T07:13:51.119+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-07-28T07:13:51.119+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-07-28T07:13:51.119+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7501M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-07-28T07:13:52.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-28T07:13:52.210+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-07-28T07:13:52.210+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-07-28T07:13:53.040+0000 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
```

That seems to be fine.

**Workspace Logs**

```
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 9
Jul 28 07:06:41 75a7aa1698de syslog-ng[14]: syslog-ng starting up; version='3.5.6'
Jul 28 07:09:01 75a7aa1698de CRON[21]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Jul 28 07:17:01 75a7aa1698de CRON[51]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Working properly. Not sure what this does exactly. But its seems to be okay.

**PHP-FPM Logs**

```
[28-Jul-2017 07:06:42] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/sqlsrv.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Jul-2017 07:06:42] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Jul-2017 07:06:42] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Jul-2017 07:06:42] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[28-Jul-2017 07:06:42] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

**NGINX Container had no substantial logs. Just the requests**

The PHP-FPM container certainly seems to be the culprit, but I can't figure it out.

**php -m**

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mongodb
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Mongodb is apparently installed so I'm not sure why I'm getting the issue with mongodb.so.

**/laradock**

```
adminer
beanstalkd-console
composer.lock
elasticsearch
haproxy
logs
memcached
mysql
php-fpm
postgres-postgis
redis
vendor
aerospike
caddy
docker-compose.yml
enabled
hhvm
log.txt
minio
neo4j
phpmyadmin
rabbitmq
rethinkdb
workspace
apache2
certbot
docs
env-env.txt
jenkins
mailhog
mongo
nginx
php-worker
README.md
selenium
xdebugPhpFpm
beanstalkd
composer.json
DOCUMENTATION
_guides
LICENSE
mariadb
mssql
pgadmin
postgres
README-zh.md
varnish
```

**/laradock/php-fpm**

```
aerospike.ini
Dockerfile-56
Dockerfile-70
Dockerfile-71
laravel.ini
laravel.pool.conf
mysql.ini
opcache.ini
xdebug.ini
```

**laravel.ini**

```
date.timezone=UTC
display_errors=on
log_errors=On

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Sets max size of post data allowed.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 20M
; Enables the MSSQL extensions
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=mongodb.so
```

**Dockerfile-70**

```
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Image Setup
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# To edit the 'php-fpm' base Image, visit its repository on Github
#    https://github.com/LaraDock/php-fpm
#
# To change its version, see the available Tags on the Docker Hub:
#    https://hub.docker.com/r/laradock/php-fpm/tags/
#

FROM laradock/php-fpm:7.0--1.2

MAINTAINER Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mandatory Software's Installation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Mandatory Software's such as ("mcrypt", "pdo_mysql", "libssl-dev", ....)
# are installed on the base image 'laradock/php-fpm' image. If you want
# to add more Software's or remove existing one, you need to edit the
# base image (https://github.com/LaraDock/php-fpm).
#

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Optional Software's Installation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Optional Software's will only be installed if you set them to `true`
# in the `docker-compose.yml` before the build.
# Example:
#   - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=true
#

#####################################
# SOAP:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_SOAP=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SOAP} = true ]; then \
    # Install the soap extension
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install libxml2-dev php-soap && \
    docker-php-ext-install soap \
;fi

#####################################
# xDebug:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then \
    # Install the xdebug extension
    pecl install xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
;fi

# Copy xdebug configration for remote debugging
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#####################################
# PHP REDIS EXTENSION FOR PHP 7
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_PHPREDIS=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PHPREDIS} = true ]; then \
    # Install Php Redis Extension
    pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis \
;fi

#####################################
# MongoDB:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MONGO=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MONGO} = true ]; then \
    # Install the mongodb extension
    pecl install mongodb && \
    docker-php-ext-enable mongodb \
;fi

#####################################
# ZipArchive:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE} = true ]; then \
    # Install the zip extension
    docker-php-ext-install zip \
;fi

#####################################
# bcmath:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_BCMATH=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_BCMATH} = true ]; then \
    # Install the bcmath extension
    docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
;fi

#####################################
# PHP Memcached:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MEMCACHED=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MEMCACHED} = true ]; then \
    # Install the php memcached extension
    curl -L -o /tmp/memcached.tar.gz "https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/php7.tar.gz" \
    && mkdir -p memcached \
    && tar -C memcached -zxvf /tmp/memcached.tar.gz --strip 1 \
    && ( \
        cd memcached \
        && phpize \
        && ./configure \
        && make -j$(nproc) \
        && make install \
    ) \
    && rm -r memcached \
    && rm /tmp/memcached.tar.gz \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
;fi

#####################################
# Exif:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_EXIF=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_EXIF} = true ]; then \
    # Enable Exif PHP extentions requirements
    docker-php-ext-install exif \
;fi

#####################################
# PHP Aerospike:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION=false
ENV INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION ${INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION}
# Copy aerospike configration for remote debugging
COPY ./aerospike.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/aerospike.ini
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION} = true ]; then \
    # Install the php aerospike extension
    curl -L -o /tmp/aerospike-client-php.tar.gz "https://github.com/luciano-jr/aerospike-client-php/archive/master.tar.gz" \
    && mkdir -p aerospike-client-php \
    && tar -C aerospike-client-php -zxvf /tmp/aerospike-client-php.tar.gz --strip 1 \
    && ( \
        cd aerospike-client-php/src/aerospike \
        && phpize \
        && ./build.sh \
        && make install \
    ) \
    && rm /tmp/aerospike-client-php.tar.gz \
    && docker-php-ext-enable aerospike \
;fi

#####################################
# Opcache:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_OPCACHE=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_OPCACHE} = true ]; then \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache \
;fi

# Copy opcache configration
COPY ./opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

#####################################
# Mysqli Modifications:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MYSQLI=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MYSQLI} = true ]; then \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
;fi

#####################################
# Tokenizer Modifications:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_TOKENIZER=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_TOKENIZER} = true ]; then \
    docker-php-ext-install tokenizer \
;fi

#####################################
# SQL SERVER:
#####################################

ARG MSSQL=false
RUN if [ ${MSSQL} = true ]; then \

    #####################################
    # Install Depenencies:
    #####################################
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y --force-yes wget apt-transport-https curl freetds-common php5-odbc libsybdb5 freetds-bin unixodbc unixodbc-dev php5-sybase && \

    #####################################
    #  The following steps were taken from
    #  Microsoft's github account:
    #  https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/wiki/Dockerfile-for-getting-pdo_sqlsrv-for-PHP-7.0-on-Debian-in-3-ways
    #####################################

    # Add PHP 7 repository
    # for Debian jessie
    # And System upgrade
        echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all" \
        | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list \
        && wget -qO- https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg \
        | apt-key add - \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get upgrade -qq && \

    # Install UnixODBC
    # Compile odbc_config as it is not part of unixodbc package
        apt-get install -y whiptail \
        unixodbc libgss3 odbcinst devscripts debhelper dh-exec dh-autoreconf libreadline-dev libltdl-dev \
        && dget -u -x http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/u/unixodbc/unixodbc_2.3.1-3.dsc \
        && cd unixodbc-*/ \
        && dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -B -d \
        && cp -v ./exe/odbc_config /usr/local/bin/ && \

    # Fake uname for install.sh
        printf '#!/bin/bash\nif [ "$*" == "-p" ]; then echo "x86_64"; else /bin/uname "$@"; fi' \
        | tee /usr/local/bin/uname \
        && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/uname && \

    # Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for Linux
    # Note: There's a copy of this tar on my hubiC
        wget -nv -O msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz \
        "https://meetsstorenew.blob.core.windows.net/contianerhd/Ubuntu%2013.0%20Tar/msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz?st=2016-10-18T17%3A29%3A00Z&se=2022-10-19T17%3A29%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=cDwPfrouVeIQf0vi%2BnKt%2BzX8Z8caIYvRCmicDL5oknY%3D" \
        && tar -xf msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz \
        && cd msodbcsql-*/ \
        && ldd lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0 \
        && ./install.sh install --accept-license \
        && ls -l /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/ \
        && odbcinst -q -d -n "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" \

    #####################################
    # Install pdo_dblib
    #####################################

    && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_dblib --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_dblib \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_dblib && \

    #####################################
    # Install sqlsrv y pdo_sqlsrv
    # extensions:
    #####################################

    pecl install sqlsrv-4.0.6 && \
    pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.6 && \

    #####################################
    # Set locales for the container
    #####################################

    apt-get install -y locales \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
;fi

#####################################
# Human Language and Character Encoding Support:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_INTL=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_INTL} = true ]; then \
    # Install intl and requirements
    apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ && \
    docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl \
;fi

#####################################
# GHOSTSCRIPT:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=false
RUN if [ ${GHOSTSCRIPT} = true ]; then \
    # Install the ghostscript extension
    # for PDF editing
    apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    poppler-utils \
    ghostscript \
;fi

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final Touch
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

ARG CATCH_WORKERS_OUTPUT=yes
ADD ./laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
ADD ./laravel.pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/

RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

Any ideas as to what could be wrong or what steps I can take to get more information?

Thanks.

**[Update]**

I'm now able to see the debugger when going to api.yellowcard.app
I have no idea what made this change. No longer getting a 500 status code when loading the page though.

```
grep -Rl no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mongodb.so
```

Doesn't seem to find it on any container except for in the logs.

Comment: What is the client and what is the server in the case of these 500 errors?  Note that 500 == Internal Server Error, so the server (whatever that is) should hopefully be logging the real problem/stack-trace.  If it isn't, then you need to improve the logging level ;)

Comment: The client is the local desktop and the server is the API in the Nginx container. The docker logs command aren't showing anything. Unfortunately I did not set the logs!

Comment: And Nginx is merely forwarding requests to the PHP-FPM container, I guess?  Assuming you can see those being correctly forwarded in the Nginx logs, then you'll need to investigate the PHP-FPM logs.  And if those aren't showing anything, then you'll need to increase the log level (I can't remember how to do that in PHP).

Comment: Try setting `catch_workers_output = yes` in your php-fpm configuration. You can do a `docker exec` to modify it.

Comment: Post the dockerfile for your `php-fpm` container if possible. That would help

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've added more information.

Comment: @WassimDhif I added it to laravel.ini in the php-fpm folder but there's no changes to the logs when running sudo docker logs laradock_php-fpm_1

Comment: Please add the build command as well that you're using

Comment: The build command for what? Is that the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I'm doing docker-compose up -d nginx mongo. I misunderstood.

Comment: your docker file just saved my life